# WPF MVVM View / UserControl Inheritance or Similar concept?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro, view-inheritance

I'm building a WPF application and using caliburn.micro for MVVM.
I'm having dozens of views (UserControls).

The views has a header body and footer.
As shown in below image, header contains two buttons for crud operation, and the footer contains a status bar.

[image: Sample View]

The header and footer parts will be same for all views, but the body contents will be different for view to view.
Currently I'm having repeated code for header and body for each view, and now I'm trying to eliminate repeating code.

To achieve this I'm thinking to make a common base view, to share with all other views.

**Current Implementation**

```
<UserControl
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel>
      <Grid Name="Header/>"
      <Grid Name="Body/>"
      <Grid Name="Footer/>"
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Trying to acheive something like**

Base View

```
<UserControl
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <StackPanel>
      <Grid Name="Header/>"
      <!-- {Placeholder for child view} -->
      <Grid Name="Footer/>"
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

ChildView

```
<Grid Name="Body"/>
```

May be my approach is wrong (I'm bit new to WPF).

My goal is to eliminate the repeating code, by inheriting some controls into the view.

How can I combine base view with child view?
Could anyone advice me to achieve my requirement?
Providing some code example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Inheritance of Views (UserControls) is not possible in `WPF`, is your Header and Footer unchanged throughout your app?

Comment: Yes It's unchanged. Just i wanted to add header & footer into my child view somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You could for example define the common header and the footer in the parent window, or in two separate user controls that you create in the XAML markup of the parent window, and then inject the child views into the same window using a `ContentControl`, e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>

        <local:HeaderUserControl />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelA}">
                    <local:ViewA />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelB}">
                    <local:ViewB />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
        <local:FooterUserControl />

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The child views doesn't know anything about the header and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your `UserControl`s just like you can nest any other element so you could do something like this

```
<UserControl x:Name="HeaderControl">
    <UserControl x:Name="ChildControl"/>
</UserControl>
```

Then you'd use a `DependencyProperty` in your header control to associate your child control with it something like this

```
public UserControl ChildControl
{
    get { return (UserControl)GetValue(ChildControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChildControlProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(UserControl), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

[This](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) article gives a nice overview - I know it says Silverlight but it uses the same basic approach.